# Why can't I import package from sibling directory in python even with use of __init__.py?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have subfolders `A` and `B`.  I am trying to import a package from sibling `A`.

I have `__init__.py`  in every subfolder and in the root project.

Yet from the file I execute in folder `B` I get the below error despite the file being present in folder `A`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/workspace/cloud-devops/B/ufw_firewall.py", line 5, in <module>
    from getparms import *
ImportError: No module named getparms
```

How to I import my package?

Thanks

Comment: I'm a little confused. Can you show a tree of your directories and what files reside in each?

Comment: `from cloud-devops.A.getparams import *` works?

Comment: Since at some point you will want to import "cloud-develops" as the whole system, you'd rather not have hiphen in the directory name, as it makes for an invalid Python package name.

Answer (score 1):

Either use relative imports, `from ..A.getparms import *`, or absolute imports `from cloud_devops.A.getparms import *`.

You can't just jump from one branch of a tree to another from the leaves without starting from the root or using relative imports.

Comment: Package names can't contain "-" - I changed it to "_" to make valid Python. (and suggested the OP to rename the dir).  Also, the number of dots in `..A` is correct if you want to rephrase yourself.

Comment: @jsbueno: Thanks for the fix. I rarely use the relative import syntax, so I was being cautious; qualifier removed.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an `__init__.py` doesn't make the modules importable from anywhere; it just means that the directory is a package. You still need to use the package name in your import:

```
from A import getparms
```

(Please don't do `from x import *`, in any case.)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `getparams` is a module and if `/home/ubuntu/workspace/` is in your `PYTHONPATH` or added via e.g. `site`...

```
import site
site.addsitedir('/home/ubuntu/workspace/')
```

... you can import in a number of ways:

```
from cloud_devops.A import getparams
from cloud_devops.A import *
```

Please note you cannot use `cloud-devops` as a module name, which is why I renamed it into `cloud_devops`. See more about this in [PEP 0008](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Package and Module Names
>
> Modules should have short, all-lowercase names. Underscores can be used in the module name if it improves readability. Python packages should also have short, all-lowercase names, although the use of underscores is discouraged.

...or you could import relatively from the script in `B`:

```
from ..A import getparams
from ..A import *
```

Two dots means up one package level. Three dots is up two levels, etc.

However, `import *` is regarded bad practice, so avoid that if possible. For readability, I would personally always do static imports, not relative ones.